# 1054 Error Messages after install phocadownload

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, joomla3.0

I upgraded to Phoca Download on my J3.1.5, now I´m getting the problems when I wanted to download the file:

```
1054 - Unknown column 'c.tokenhits' in 'field list'

SELECT c.catid, c.filename, c.directlink, c.link_external, c.access, c.confirm_license, c.metakey, c.metadesc, cc.access as cataccess, cc.accessuserid as cataccessuserid, c.tokenhits FROM yav95_phocadownload AS c, yav95_phocadownload_categories AS cc WHERE c.id = 33 AND c.published = 1 AND c.approved = 1 AND c.catid = cc.id AND cc.access IN (1,1,5) AND ( c.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR c.publish_up <= '2013-10-13 13:35:28' ) AND ( c.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR c.publish_down >= '2013-10-13 13:35:28' ) ORDER BY c.ordering LIMIT 0, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

since Phoca Download version 3.0.2, there are new table columns in database tables. When you upgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.0.2, Joomla! extension manager correctly reads the update instructions and update your database.

But when you upgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.0.3 or similar, it can happen, that the tables will be not upgraded. You will see e.g. the above mentioned error.

In such case, Phoca Download file table needs to be updated manually. Run your phpMyAdmin application and add the following SQL queries in your database.

See the guide which described it step by step:

http://www.phoca.cz/documents/16-joomla/759-how-to-solve-problems-which-occur-while-upgrading-joomla-extensions